# SQL Server - Is there a relationship between lazy writer and ldf read?

Tags: sql-server

The Disk Queue Length ( Disk Read Time / 100 ) value on drive D has increased.

There is only an ldf file on drive D.

[image]

When the number increased, Lazy Writer was performed.

Does Lazy Writer read ldf?

[image]

If not, when does reading the ldf file occur?
(Except restore)

Comment: `ldf` is the extension of the transaction log which is used in *all* transactions, explicit or implicit. You should check what's executing so many individual transactgions at 14:45. It could be a badly written application that executes 1000 separate INSERTs instead of a single INSERT with 1000 values, or a written ORM code that reads 1000 items, modifies them and then writes them back one at a time. Such problems can be fixed by fixing the code and using eg a single `INSERT .. SELECT` or `UPDATE..SELECT` statement to modify all records at once

Comment: The above table shows Read Time. 
I think, If DML has occurred, the WRITE TIME should have increased.
Although not listed in the table, the batch request and transaction did not increase.

Comment: The server has to *read* the transaction log records each time a transaction commits or rolls back. *Especially* when a rollback occurs, because it needs those records to return the data rows to their original state. The requests/transactions wouldn't increase if someone rolled back a big transaction